# scanning string in c

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, gets

```
   int main( )
    {
        char str[200];
        int n,tc;
        scanf("%d",&tc);
        while(tc--)
         {
           scanf("%d",&n);
           gets(str);
           puts(str);
        }
    return 34;
    }
```

Why this code  is not scanning   no. of strings(str) equals to tc?
Platform  UBUNTU 10.04

Comment: The main declaration is not supposed to be like that... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is horrible code.  Why are you doing the first `scanf` argument into `tc` (which should be of type `char **`)?

Comment: we can declare integer variable inside main()  ,

Comment: n and tc by default  integer value

Comment: Ok, but your `main` can have only few particular signatures (the classic one is `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`), you can't put there arbitrary parameters; besides, relying on "implicit `int`" is considered bad style.

Comment: Yes, although you shouldn't ever use `gets` (it is a potential security problem, since it reads input from keyboard disregarding the size of your buffer); you should use `fgets` passing to it the size of your buffer.

Comment: Besides the horrid stuff noted by others, please tell us exactly what input you give to this program, what the program does, and what you expected it to do instead.

Comment: See  , I have compiled my code here  http://ideone.com/sSRcf with the inputs  but is giving runtime error

Comment: Don't use `gets()` even in toy code.  Pretend it does not exist.  Better yet, replace it with: `char *gets(char *str) { assert("Do not use gets() - ever!" == 0); return 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break down the code one line at a time (more or less):

```
scanf("%d",&tc);
```

reads an integer into tc.

```
while(tc--)
```

loops tc times

```
    scanf("%d",&n);
```

reads an integer into n

```
    gets(str);
```

reads the rest of the line into `str`, removing the trailing newline

```
    puts(str);
```

prints out the string, followed by a newline

So you're reading an integer, and then reading that many integer+rest of line pairs and printing out the lines (but not the integers -- they get thrown away).  Reading an integer involves skipping any blank space (spaces, tabs, and entire blank lines) before the integer but not any after it, so this can be a little confusing, depending on what kind of input you're feeding to the program.

In your example, you say you're feeding it the input:

```
3
4
anil kuma
2
abc
4
ams
```

So lets go through the program and see what it does:

- read the integer `3` into tc
- loop 3 times
- (first loop)

  - read `4` into n
  - read the rest of the line (blank) into `str`,
  - print the blank line
- (second loop)

  - try to read an integer into n, but the input (`anil kuma`) isn't an integer, so sets the error flag on stdin
  - read the rest of the line (`anil kuma`) into str
  - prints `anil kuma`
- (third loop)

  - read `2` into n
  - read the rest of the line (blank) into `str`
  - print the blank line
- loop is done, return exit code 34.

You never check the return value of functions or the error code on stdin, so the fact that you got an error trying to read an integer on the second iteration is completely invisible.

You might get an output more like what you are expecting by changing your scanf calls to:

```
scanf("%d ", &n);
```

Note the extra space after the %d conversion, which causes scanf to read and throw away whiltespace until it finds a non-whitespace character.  This will cause it to throw away the newlines after the integers, as well as any following blank lines and any spaces/tabs at the beginning of the next non-blank line

Comment: got it,needs space after %d during scanning n.

Comment: Note that the space after the %d has other effects -- namely skipping over blank lines -- which you may or may not care about.

Answer (score 3):

Here what I get on my machine:

```
vovanium@microvovanium:~/tmp$ cc whoa.c 
whoa.c: In function ‘main’:
whoa.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
/tmp/cc1r5dZe.o: In function `main':
whoa.c:(.text+0x4b): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
vovanium@microvovanium:~/tmp$ ./a.out 
3
12qwe
qwe
34asd
asd
56zxc
zxc
```

So it seems it scans.

It seems you're using K&R C, but it is not good idea. Use ANSI/ISO C standard.

1. There's no `#include <stdio>`, and the start of program. It is needed to use `scanf()`, `gets()` and `puts()`. It is especially necessary when using variable arguments functions, like `printf` and `scanf` (and thus my compiler complains).
2. You did not declared parameters types for main(). Main have prototype `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.
3. You used function parameters as local variables, better declare them in function body. You have to have: `int tc;` and `int n;` just after `{`.
4. Possible value returned from main() is defined in `<stdlib.h>` and can be `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAIL` or commonly used 0 or 1 (of course you may use other values, but you have to ensure, that they're meaningful in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I got it,error  is  in in line

```
 scanf("%d", &n);
```

It needs space after %d

```
 scanf("%d ", &n);
```